# Store class call parameter as attributes

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have an abstract class and when I subclass it I would like the parameter I pass to be stored as attributes for internal use.
My class definition goes like this :

```
class Parent(object):
    def __new__(cls, a, b, c, d, e):
        obj = super(Parent, cls).__new__(cls)
        a, b, c, d, e = *(float(_) for _ in (a, b, c, d)), int(e)
        keys = ("_a", "_b", "_c", "_d", "_e")
        obj.__dict__.update({k: v for k, v in zip(keys, (a, b, c, d, e))})
        return obj

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a #same for b, c, d, e
```

Is there any common pattern or better way to do this ?